# entity framework can call property on null in expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, nullreferenceexception, linq-expressions

I have code to select some objects in the database like this:

```
db.ObjectTypes.GroupJoin(db.Terms, t => t.Id, term => term.ObjectTypeId, (t, terms) => new Term()
{
    Type = t.Type,
    ObjectTypeId = t.Id,
    Deadline = ((int?)terms.FirstOrDefault().Deadline ?? 0),
});
```

The question is how does it come that this line works when there are no objects in terms, so the `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`

```
((int?)terms.FirstOrDefault().Deadline ?? 0)
```

For me this code looks like it could crash while it's actually save.So I was expecting to get a null reference exception in this case. I tried to change the line to

```
(terms.FirstOrDefault()?.Deadline ?? 0)
```

That way you know it can be null, but this isn't valid in the expression.

I know it works and doesn't give an exception because the code isn't actually executed but translated to sql, but I'm searching for something explaining why its done like this and not possible in the other way?

Comment: The hint is that the code isn't executed. It's converted into SQL in such a way that the property isn't called if the value is `null`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know it is converted but it still looks like invalid code, while that something that would look valid isn't accepted.

Comment: Not supporting  "the other way" is not EF fault. First, the `?.` operator didn't exist at the time EF was developed. Second and most important, as you noticed, the operator `?.` is not supported in C# expression trees (because MS devs had no clear idea and didn't decide what type of (new) expression should represent it), hence EF and other expression translators can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like *Enigmativity* mentioned, the code will not be executed. Because `terms` is empty no grouping will be done and therefore no `FirstOrDefault()` will be executed.

You can see it in the following example. (Just a simple one)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class static Program {

    public static void Main() 
    {
        var terms = new List<Term>();

        var result = ((int?)terms.FirstOrDefault().Deadline ?? 0);        
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        var result2 = (terms.FirstOrDefault()?.Deadline ?? 0);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }

    private class Term
    {
        public int Deadline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code above will be translated into the following one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public class Program
{
    private class Term
    {
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated]
        private int <Deadline>k__BackingField;

        public int Deadline
        {
            [CompilerGenerated]
            get
            {
                return this.<Deadline>k__BackingField;
            }
            [CompilerGenerated]
            set
            {
                this.<Deadline>k__BackingField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<C.Term> source = new List<C.Term>();
        int? num = new int?(source.FirstOrDefault<C.Term>().Deadline);
        int value = num.HasValue ? num.GetValueOrDefault() : 0;
        Console.WriteLine(value);

        // just added this line for more readability
        C.Term expr_3A = source.FirstOrDefault<C.Term>();
        int value2 = (expr_3A != null) ? expr_3A.Deadline : 0;
        Console.WriteLine(value2);
    }
}
```

You can see that your line you mentioned (`((int?)terms.FirstOrDefault().Deadline ?? 0)`) will result in a `NullReferenceException`. The `?.` will avoid the exception.
You could try it [here](http://tpcg.io/cOwZOb) or just create a `Console Application` with the example code above.